# How to get all the input elements data of a current div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code:

```
<div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item prescribeData">
        <div class="mt-repeater-cell">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                <i class="fa fa-stethoscope blue-icon-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" id="prescribe_test" class="form-control typeahead-prescribetest input-circle-right" placeholder="Prescribe Test">
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block">Name of Investigation</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                <i class="fa fa-stethoscope blue-icon-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" id="diagnosis_input" class="form-control typeahead-diagnosis input-circle-right" placeholder="Duration of Investigation (Optional)">
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block">e.g. Once, Weekly, Monthly</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div class="col-md-1 pull-right col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                   <a href="javascript:;" style="margin-right:20px;" class="btn-circle prescribeAddData btn green-meadow mt-repeater-btn-inline"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                   </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to get all the input elements data in a variable using a JQuery code:

I am currently using this code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.prescribeAddData', function ()
        {
            console.log($(this).closest($(".prescribeData :input")));
        });
```

But this code doesn't display the data that the elements are holding after inputting in it.

How can I fix this logic?

Comment: Please show more code...we have no idea what `this` is or where you call it from. Read [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated my code please have a view at it

Comment: There is no `<a class="prescribeAddData">` shown in the html for the click event to occur on

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated the code

Comment: $(this).closest($(".prescribeData :input")) this code gives to you only one element that is nearest element. $(this).closest(".prescribeData").find('input').each(function(i,e){ console.log(e.val())}) It should give to you correct. Please be careful about syntax

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ it showing error in console that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: I dont have computer now hence i informed to you careful about syntax if you open fiddle then can modify the code on it

Comment: You can't traverse up and down using the same selector. Traverse up then use find()

Comment: its showing an error in console that `e.val() is not a function`

Comment: Show us all the code. You aren't showing using `val()` anywhere. Again read through [mcve]

Comment: This is the all code i dont have more than that

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `find` method to find all elements that are children of a specific element then iterate over them, and store the values in an array for example.

```js
var inputFields = $('.prescribeData').find('input');
var values = [];
inputFields.each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val())
})
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item prescribeData">
        <div class="mt-repeater-cell">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                <i class="fa fa-stethoscope blue-icon-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" id="prescribe_test" class="form-control typeahead-prescribetest input-circle-right" placeholder="Prescribe Test">
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block">Name of Investigation</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left capsule-lightblue">
                                <i class="fa fa-stethoscope blue-icon-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" id="diagnosis_input" class="form-control typeahead-diagnosis input-circle-right" placeholder="Duration of Investigation (Optional)">
                        </div>
                        <span class="help-block">e.g. Once, Weekly, Monthly</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want only the values inside the element not the whole input thing attributes n all

Comment: This is a click on the document and not related to OP's question. OP is clearly trying to work within `repeater` instance

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to get the elements. I updated my answer to add the values in an array. You can write the javascript code into a function and call it whenever you want, you can return the values from the function for example.